# how to upload apk with Google play custom app API

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play-console

I am trying to upload a custom app to play store. I am stuck with how to get the account Id that I need to pass to the create method.

the documentation says that I need to call the following api but, I am not sure how to make the call and get service account.

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/delegatePrivateApp?service_account=serviceAccountEmail&continueUrl=callbackUrl

I appreciate any help, thanks.

[Google Play Doc](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/custom-app-api/) and 
[Java Doc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/playcustomapp/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/playcustomapp/package-summary.html)

Here is my code so far:

```
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/Users/mie/Downloads/Google-Play-Android-Developer-9b6977dc98fc.json"))
            .createScoped(Collections.singleton(PlaycustomappScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER));

    Playcustomapp app = new Playcustomapp.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    app.accounts().customApps().create(...);
```

Comment: if this solution works for you please mark so that whole community can immediately see that and benefit from it. Otherwise, please leave a feedback below my answer so that other visitors can see it too.

Answer (score 2):

You probably were referring to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/custom-app-api/get-started#create_a_service_account). It says that you have to create a service account manually and that it has to belong to a Cloud Project. Here are the steps:

> 1. Open the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Login if prompted.
> 2. From the projects list, choose the project that you selected or created when enabling the API.
> 3. From the main menu, select IAM & Admin > Service accounts > Create service account.
> 4. Enter a name for your service account and select Furnish a new private key. Then click Create.

Once you followed this steps the service account email will look like this: `service-account-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. You should put it into the URL you mentioned along with the URL the visitor should be redirected to after. Like this:

> https://play.google.com/apps/publish/delegatePrivateApp?service_account=service-account-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com&continueUrl=https://www.example.com

I also advise to review the documentation once again.